# "select" query using "PetaPoco" ORM

Tags: c#, .net, petapoco

I tried something like the following, but it didn't work.

`var _records = new string[] {"SqlServer", "IIS" };`

`var result = db.Fetch<EntityRecords>(@" select * from tblRecords where RecordName IN rs", new { rs = _records });`

and also i have tried another way like the following, but same problem

`var _records = new string[] {"SqlServer", "IIS" };`

```
  var query = PetaPoco.Sql.Builder.Select("*").From("tblRecords").Where("RecordName IN (@rs)",new { rs = _records });
  var result = db.Query<EntityRecords>(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one should be

```
var result = db.Fetch<EntityRecords>(@" select * from tblRecords where RecordName IN (@rs)", new { rs = _records });
```

or

```
var result = db.Fetch<EntityRecords>(@" select * from tblRecords where RecordName IN (@0)", _records);
```

The second one I'm not too sure about because the following tests pass

```
    [Fact]
    public void Append_GivenArrayAndValue_ShouldBeValid()
    {
        // Simple collection parameter expansion
        _sql = Sql.Builder.Append("@0 IN (@1) @2", 20, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 30);

        _sql.SQL.ShouldBe("@0 IN (@1,@2,@3) @4");
        _sql.Arguments.Length.ShouldBe(5);
        _sql.Arguments[0].ShouldBe(20);
        _sql.Arguments[1].ShouldBe(1);
        _sql.Arguments[2].ShouldBe(2);
        _sql.Arguments[3].ShouldBe(3);
        _sql.Arguments[4].ShouldBe(30);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Append_GivenArrayAndNamedValue_ShouldBeValid1()
    {
        // Simple collection parameter expansion
        _sql = Sql.Builder.Append("@p1 IN (@p2) @p3", new { p1 = 20 }, new { p2 =  new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }}, new { p3 = 30 });

        _sql.SQL.ShouldBe("@0 IN (@1,@2,@3) @4");
        _sql.Arguments.Length.ShouldBe(5);
        _sql.Arguments[0].ShouldBe(20);
        _sql.Arguments[1].ShouldBe(1);
        _sql.Arguments[2].ShouldBe(2);
        _sql.Arguments[3].ShouldBe(3);
        _sql.Arguments[4].ShouldBe(30);
    }
```